# Where to find the linking settings Panel

Tags: xcode4.2

I have moved to Xcode 4.2, since that, i didn't find the Settings Panel where to configure flags and a lot of parameters. The window i look for is this in Xcode 3:
[image]

Can you please guide m step by step to find out that Panels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quote from [this site](http://meandmark.com/blog/2011/03/xcode-4-accessing-build-settings/):

> To access build settings in Xcode 4, select the project file from the project navigator on the left side of the project window. The project file should be at the top of the project navigator. Selecting the project file opens the project settings editor. The project settings editor is Xcode 4′s replacement for Xcode 3′s project and target inspectors. Select either the project or a target from the project settings editor. Click the Build Settings button at the top of the editor. Now you should see a list of the project’s build settings.

In the `Build Settings` tab, there is a section named `Linking` which is what you're looking for. See [this picture](http://community.rti.com/sites/default/files/users/Ronald/image9.png) from [this site](http://community.rti.com/content/forum-topic/dds-development-mac-os-using-xcode-4).